# Function Fill some field and Submit on Select

Tags: javascript, submit, onchange, onselect

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function FillCode(info) {
  var str = '';
  if (info != '') { str = info; }
  document.getElementById('coupon_code').value = str;
}

</script>

<div class="input-box">
<input class="input-text" type="hidden" id="coupon_code" name="coupon_code" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getCouponCode()) ?>" />
<select id="SBox" style="background-color: #666;" onchange="FillCode(value)">
      <option value="">Select Code</option>
      <option value="CODEDISCOUNT">X% Discount</option>
    </select>
```

> I want to make this in a automatic send on select the X% Discount
>   option on dropdown.

On select this fill the Coupon Code form, but i need to press the submit button to auto update the form.

Answer (score 1):

Would it be acceptable to use jQuery to do this ?

If so, I have put up a working example **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/UW7Dp/5/)**

Using jQuery this is what you would do :

```
$("#SBox").change(function() {
    //alert($(this).val());
    $("input#coupon_code").val($(this).val());
    $("form").submit();
});
```

Comment: Hi, the problem is with jQuery, my website not work with jQuery, so for this i have maded a simple script to autocomplete the form, but not to send. :(